# Why is A* considered as a recursive search algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, recursion

I'm currently studying informed search algorithms.

I've found a paper telling that A* is a recursive algorithm but I can't see where's the recursion part of this algorithm.

Why is A* considered as a recursive algorithm?

Comment: I don't think this can really be answered without context. For example, anything that can be implemented with iteration can be implemented with recursion, and vice-versa. What was the exact paper you were reading?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What was the paper you found?  Can you give a full citation (authors, title, where published) and a link to a free PDF of the paper?  Can you give a quote with an excerpt of the relevant part of the paper?  You can click the 'edit' link under your question to edit it and add additional information.  After the question is edited it can be considered for re-opening.